# Change background image of page dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to change background image of my page dynamically.
Code in my aspx page is:

```
<li style="background:url(/newtheme/images/city-images/City-name.jpg) no-repeat center 93px;"></li>
```

**/newtheme/images/city-images/** this part of URL is staic.

while City-name.jpg will keep on changing like California.jpg, Dubai.jpg, etc.

Please help,
Thanks

Comment: Either do it in JavaScript or make it a server side control where you set the style attribute

Comment: Please tell how can I make a server side control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it server-side in your the give your LI an ID and runat="server" attribute:

```
<li runat="server" id="liCity"></li>
```

Then in your C# code you will be able to do something like

```
liCity.Style["background"] = string.Format("url(/newtheme/images/city-images/{0}.jpg) no-repeat center 93px;", "Moscow");
```